# How to add a css class to a meta box via php

Tags: php, css

I'm working with a code similar to the following and I need to get a meta box to have a certain css class.

As in the example:

```
add_meta_box('meta_box_id_name', // $id
              'Meta Box Title Name', // $title
              'CSS Class Here', // $css class
             );
```

Is there anyway to add a css class via php when adding a meta box?

Thanks.

Comment: use meta_box name as key and css class as value

Comment: There is no such thing as a CSS class, you seem to be talking about  HTML classes. They are just commonly used in CSS selectors. The next most common thing they are used in is JavaScript DOM manipulation.

Comment: HI, thanks for your help. The only way I was able to get this to work was to add the div classes in the php. 

I was able to change the metabox css class by javascript but it slowed down my site, so eventually I used the above method.